# Java While loop only works when printing

Tags: java, loops

I have a while loop in my program that does things only when a certain condition becomes true, but it should do nothing until then. I had it printing in the console the word "ran" every time it ran the loop, but that's no longer necessary. When I remove the system.out.println the loop closes instantly and ceases to work. Why does this happen?

```
int INFINITE = 1;
try {
    S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("saucyMMO", "logins.txt"));
    while (INFINITE == 1) {
        System.out.println();
        if (tryToLogin == true) {
            INFINITE = 0;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new  InputStreamReader(object.getObjectContent()));
            String lineValue = null;
            while((lineValue = br.readLine()) != null && loggedInAs == null) {
            String splitResult[] = lineValue.split(",");
                boolean retVal = splitResult[0].equals(ui.usernameLogin.getText());
                boolean retVal2 = splitResult[1].equals(ui.passwordLogin.getText());
                if (retVal == true && retVal2 == true) {
                    loggedInAs = splitResult[0];
            System.out.println("logged in as : " + loggedInAs);
                } else if (retVal && !retVal2){
                    System.out.println("User exists, but password is incorrect");
                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    }
 } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {

 } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {

 } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

I added in exception handling for AmazonServiceException and AmazonClientException but I receive no errors with or without the system.out.println.

Comment: How do you know that it exists the loop?

Comment: You are swallowing exceptions in your catch block.  This is a **horrible** idea.

Comment: ... especially if your program is not behaving as you expect.

Comment: Even when I use the same input as I do without the printing, it will not change the String "loggedInAs" or print out "logged in as : somthing"

Comment: Other notes:  `retVal` should be `usernameMatches`, `retVal1` should be `passwordMatches`; some systems, especially when the username is an email address, often ignore case - something to consider.  Don't compare booleans to constants - just use the value of the boolean itself.  The way you use `INFINITE` is somewhat misleading - you're using as if it were a boolean, but I have a feeling you were wanting a limited number of tries...

Comment: Why is `INFINITE` an int instead of a boolean? You could use some refactoring for your while loop - if it's really supposed to be infinite, consider using `while (true)` and `break`ing when necessary. As it stands, you'll get kicked out of your loop if an exception occurs (which you swallow silently) or if it does what you expect (which can also fail silently in the `else` case where the username doesn't match). Also, you don't need the `== true` in any if statement (ever). And the indentation hurts - closing braces should be at the same level as the opening statement.

Comment: My guess is either the username doesn't exist or one of the exceptions that are being swallowed silently are triggering.

Answer (score 5):

You are swallowing Exceptions in your catch blocks.

This is a **very very** bad idea.

The problem with this is it makes it **very** hard to debug Exceptions.

You are currently demonstrating this exact scenario.

Add `e.printStackTrace()` to your other catch blocks.

When you run your program you will see an informative stack trace.

Reading the stack trace will help you figure out what's going wrong.

It's pretty clear that you're throwing one of those Amazon related Exceptions.

Comment: This should be a comment...

Comment: I kinda thought so, too... and I already commented.  I guess I was trying to put it here so I could elaborate on how to fix the problem or continue to debug.

Comment: Thanks for that, it does help clear some things up, but it still does not make sense why it should matter if the while statement prints "ran"

Comment: Actually, it makes a lot of sense.  You're program was executing up to that point, then throwing an Exception (that you're swallowing quietly).

Comment: I'd say its under hints posted as answers, usually for homework but not inappropriate in general

Comment: The s3 object is working perfectly though, I am able to download data

Comment: Add some error handling code and find out what the problem is.  Before you were intentionally ignoring any possible feedback that comes from Exceptions.

Comment: Generally if im catching an exception but I dont think its ever actually going to happen so I dont bother dealing with the catch I rethrow a runtime exception just in case I was wrong, that way it hits me in the face and I fix it. Never ever ever leave a catch block empty, even if you think it will never come up

Comment: It looks like if the username doesn't match it will also kick out of the loop silently.

Comment: Yes, but I am very sure that the username matches.

Comment: @user1952381 Thats what all the empty catchers say. What happened when you put e.printStackTrace in both of those empty catch blocks?

Comment: With the System.print I got no errors, just alot of "ran"s. without nothing printed.

Comment: You should print if the username doesn't match anyway, just in case.

Comment: @user1952381 Ive seen programs so tied up in knots I would never have believed it if I hadnt seen it, don't discount a problem (like these exceptions) unless you've **proved** it isnt the problem